# prevent Authentification for specific route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a MVC Webapplication. It uses Forms auhtentification.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="90" />
</authentication>
```

How can i bypass this for a single route, like xyz.com/us/ht/ht?

I want to bypass the whole functionality to prevent getting aspxanonymous cookies and i dont want entries in the membership db for this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVC4 just add the `[AllowAnonymous]` tag to your controller action.

Otherwise do it in your web.config like this

```
<configuration>
   <location path="route/thatanon/isallowed">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: that not bypasses the authtentification. it allows anonymous. i edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: This doesn't create entries in your membership DB. Why are you worried about an anonymous cookie?

Comment: it is for an affiliate partner landingpage. normaly you would put this page outside of mvc, but it's inside. anonymous auth is stored in the profile table by default. i get 1.000.000+ requests from affiliate partner per day, so it would be nice to disable it completly. the correct solution would be to put these landingpages outside to static html files but if there is a way to bypass the anonymous stuff i would do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use a custom AnonymousIdentificationModule for the route /us/ht/ht/.

The stuff is handled here ->

System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdetificationModule